# Laravel 5.3: How do I get the direct count, when I have used the eager nested relationship?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In my controller I have used:

```
->with('city.location.propertyCount')
```

In Model the method is define as:

```
public function propertyCount() {
    return $this->property()
        ->selectRaw("location_id, count(*) as property_count")
        ->groupBy('location_id');
 }
```

What I get in response object:

```
"property_count":
[
    {
        "location_id": XXX,
        "property_count": 1
    }
]
```

How I want the count to appear in the response object:

```
"property_count": 1
```

Comment: return $this->property()
        ->selectRaw(" count(*) as property_count")->groupBy('location_id')->first();

Comment: @JYoThI BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2451:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()

Comment: try this ->groupBy('location_id')->value('property_count');

Comment: @JYoThI Not working,FatalThrowableError in Builder.php line 502:
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer